# Valid US tourist visa, but expired passport

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, dual-nationality

So I'm a dual citizen. One is an EU country so it’s under the VWP, and the other is not. I have a valid us tourist visa on the non-EU passport but it's about to expire and at the time. Because of the country's situation is very hard to renew the passport.

So my question is if I have a valid visa on an expired passport without being able to renew it, should I just simply apply and use the ESTA on the EU passport and disregard the visa on the other.

P.S. - I’ve heard that if you have a valid visa you shouldn’t even apply for the ESTA and I know people that have been troubled during immigration because of this.

Comment: Is your non-VWP passport about to expire or the visa in it?

Comment: The non-VWP passport will soon expire but the visa in it will still be valid after that for some years.

Answer (score 1):

You can travel under the VWP with your VWP-eligible passport even though you have a valid visa in your non-VWP passport.  This is true whether the non-VWP passport is valid or expired.

I am unfortunately unable to find an authoritative reference to support this, however.  There are some similar questions here that lead to this conclusion, however:

- [Dual nationality : ESTA and non ESTA citizen with one valid nonimmigrant USA visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/58778/19400)
- [Can a dual national use VWP with one passport when they have a valid US visa in the other (non-VWP-eligible) passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/86400/19400)
- [Dual citizenship passports and visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/64790/19400)