# Can I go to USA with a Canadian Passport even though I am from another country?

Tags: visas, usa, passports, canada

I am from a country that requires to get a valid visa to enter USA. I also have a Canadian passport. Am I still required to have visa to enter USA? I have no criminal record and I'm just going there to visit a friend.

Comment: What country are you from?

Answer (score 10):

You are a dual citizen of Canada and another country and you wish to enter the USA on your Canadian passport.

You are free to do so. Trumps Executive Order barring citizens of certain countries (including dual citizens) from entering the USA is not longer in effect.

http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/canadian-affected-trump-travel-ban-refugees-immigrants-1.3957059

> Canadian dual citizens can travel freely to the U.S. despite Trump
>   travel ban. Furthermore, NSA Flynn confirmed that holders of Canadian passports, including dual citizens, will not be affected by the ban. Trudeau stated that the government has been assured that Canadian citizens traveling on Canadian passport will be dealt with ‎in the usual process. He further said that they will continue to share on this and other channels.

Comment: And the new order, which might come into effect because the courts haven'treached a final ruling on it, explicitly allows dual citizens who otherwise would be affected to travel using the passport of their non-affected citizenship.

Answer (score 7):

As a Canadian citizen, in most situations [you do not need a visa to enter the United States](https://ca.usembassy.gov/visas/do-i-need-a-visa/). The rules around Canadian citizens visiting the US are relatively relaxed (just don't try to work!). You need not mention your other citizenship(s), or bring any passport other than your Canadian one.

Answer (score 1):

Overnight my close vote for this being a duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/64891/4188 has disappeared. So then I will copy that answer here then:

I sent the question as posted here to the CBP (because noone sources their answers and it reads to me as beliefs held about passports not facts) and received the information below. Based on this, despite it is not a straight yes or no (they never do that) I believe I am allowed to present a Canadian passport because otherwise why would they point out what happens if I present one. I will seek further clarification in April once I get my passport and add it to my NEXUS at the NEXUS centre but for now I think I am good.

So, without further ado, their reply:

---

Thank you for contacting the U.S. Customs and Border Protection (CBP) INFO Center.

A Canadian citizen does not need a visa to visit the United States.

If you present a Hungarian passport: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/572

If you present a Canadian passport: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/619

If you have any other questions or concerns, please feel free to call our toll-free number 877-CBP-5511 (877-227-5511). From outside the United States, please call 202-325-8000 - you may incur charges from your telephone service provider for this call. Our service hours are Monday through Friday from 9 a.m.-4 p.m. Eastern Time. We are closed on all U.S. federal holidays.

We hope our answers ease your entry into the United States. Please understand these answers are informational only, The CBP officer who speaks with you upon arrival determines the admissibility of goods and visitors.

Thank you again for contacting the CBP INFO Center.

Sincerely,

CBP INFO Center