# My country does not allow Dual nationality.....but my 2nd country has no issue

Tags: visas, dual-nationality

My original country does not allow dual nationality but the adopted country does.

I have visas for US & Canada on my original country passport and i need them to visit these countries, my new passport does not give me visa free access.

As per the laws of my country i must surrender my passport but if i do i loose my visas.....should i retain my passport. Do other countries consider it a crime that i own 2 passports?

Comment: Does your original country consider you to have lost your nationality there on accepting adopted country nationality? If so, using a visa in your old passport might be considered deceptive by the country that issued the visa.

Comment: Have you already given up citizenship of your original country?  (This would invalidate your visa.)  Or does your original country still think you are a citizen?  (In which case your visa remain valid.)

Comment: See also: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72532/status-of-b1-b2-visa-after-citizenship-change

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan it's usually not that simple. Some countries don't allow dual citizenship but the loss of Citizenship is not automatic. There is a due process of law. Unless OP tells us his original citizenship, it would be impossible to answer his question.

Comment: @greatone In practice loss of citizenship is never automatic: other countries are not notified when you acquire a new citizenship.

Comment: @jpatokal in some countries, like India, you cease to be a citizen the moment you recieve another country's passport.

Comment: @greatone Yes, in legal theory, but *in practice* that only happens when India *finds out* that you have another passport.

Comment: As @greatone has mentioned, this question can be better answered if we know OP's original country'nationality.

Comment: You have to **live in reality**.  Literally 10s of million of people get a passport from country B and simply **don't tell** country A that they got passport B.   The idea that country A can "take away" your passport because you happened to get a passport from B, is, utterly immoral and despicable and disgusting.  By all means use your judgement, but you have to "live in reality", vast numbers of people have more passports, even when country A says you "can't" do that.

Comment: @jpatokal Some countries require that the loss of citizenship does not happen, even in theory, unless there is a due process of law. In India, however, you will be deemed to have lost the citizenship the moment you acquire another.