# dual citizenship/visas

Tags: visas, usa, canada, australia

Hoping someone can answer this question!

I am an Australian citizen and I live in Canada on a PR card but my two kids were born and we live in Canada.  I have two children who both have Australian and Canadian citizenship and passports.

We are going to the US for 2 weeks and I was going to use my children's Canadian passports to enter the US but, because the kids also have a Australian passport, do they need a visa to enter?

I have applied for an ESTA for myself as I will be travelling on my Australian passport but i am just worried that I need an extra visa for my kids even though they will be travelling on their Canadian passport!

I appreciate any advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Also helpful [Dual nationality : ESTA and non ESTA citizen with one valid nonimmigrant USA visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58778/dual-nationality-esta-and-non-esta-citizen-with-one-valid-nonimmigrant-usa-vis) and [Dual citizenship passports and visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64790/dual-citizenship-passports-and-visas)

Comment: In most cases, people with more than one citizenship can benefit from the least restrictive requirements by showing the appropriate documents.  That is, people generally require visas but if they have the appropriate passport they are exempt.  There are some cases where this is not true (where a restriction depends on someone's citizenship regardless of what other citizenships they might hold), but it certainly *is* true for an Australian/Canadian dual citizen flying to the US.

Comment: so in other words they are fine travelling on there Canadian passport!

Comment: i appreciate your information

Answer (score 3):

Since they have their Canadian passports (and will travel to the US with those) they do not need a US visa or ESTA for this trip regardless of their dual Aussie nationality.

> In most circumstances, Canadian citizens do not require visitor, business, transit or other visas to enter the United States, either from Canada or from other countries.

Source: [U.S. Embassy & Consulates in Canada](https://ca.usembassy.gov/visas/do-i-need-a-visa/)

There are some exceptions but your trip does not fall under those, you can read about the exceptions on the link above.

Comment: i Appreciate your advice

Comment: To benefit from this, of course, they need to be travelling on Canadian passports.